# deleting pointer after return

Tags: c++, pointers

```
Matrix * Matrix::transpose()
{

    Matrix *m = new Matrix(*this->numCols, *this->numRows, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < *this->numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *this->numCols; j++)
        {
            m->setValue(j, i, this->getValue(i, j));
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

Hello all. My memory keeps increasing after transposing matricies. How can i solve that, by deleting returned m(how to do it?) or deleting this->~Matrix() ?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to return a `Matrix` instead of a pointer to a newed object.

Comment: Try this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223399/deleting-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: You guys are so fast thank you for answering me! I will try both of them.

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management and not smart pointers?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i tried smart pointers but couldnt go far. I will try smart pointers too, should i use uniqe_ptr ?

Comment: @BarbarosBaturay No you don't need pointers of any type. Smart pointers aren't the solution when the problem is using dynamic allocation. The solution is to not use dynamic allocation.

Comment: if you are ready to redesign the class *Matrix*, the best option will be *std::vector<std::vector<Type>>*, as it provides dynamically contiguous memory allocation, and good to go, without bothering about the manual *delete*, like in your original case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use any pointers. There is no reason to use `new` here. Just do

```
Matrix Matrix::transpose()
{

    Matrix m {*this->numCols, *this->numRows, false};

    for (int i = 0; i < *this->numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *this->numCols; j++)
        {
            m.setValue(j, i, this->getValue(i, j));
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

Also another thing, why are you putting `this` everywhere? If you want to make clear something is a member, just prefix/postfix it like `m_memberName`, `mMemberName` or `memberName_`.

Comment: Well, thank you for advice. Also i did somethink like void transpose and changing the values if the rows or cols are the same etc. Is it an efficient way ?

Comment: `Matrix m(*this->numCols, *this->numRows, false);`

Comment: Yes, that's even better. Editing now.