# template && invalid operands in operator+

Tags: c++

```
friend myList<T> operator +( myList<T> &c1,myList<T> &c2);

myList<T> operator +(myList<T> &c1, myList<T> &c2)
{
    int len1 = c1.getLength();
    int len2 = c2.getLength();
    int newLen = len1+len2;
    int newSize = newLen;
    T * newList = new T[newSize];
    for(int i = 0;i<len1;i++){
        newList[i] = c1.data[i];
    }
    for(int j=len1;j<newLen;j++){
        newList[j] = c2.data[j-len1];
    }
    delete c1.data;
    c1.data = newList;
    c1.size = newSize;
    c1.length = newLen;
    return *c1;
}
void main(){
    myList<int> *a = new myList<int>(5);
    myList<int> *b = new myList<int>(5);
    a+b;
}
```

errormessage:invalid operands of types '`myList < int >*`' and '`myList< int > *`' to binary 'operator+' when I call '`a+b`', so how should I do to make it right ?

Comment: You have two pointers, and the operator expects references to two *non-pointers*... Consider removing the pointers and `new`... C++ classes are **not** Java classes... Try `(*a)+(*b);`

Comment: Why are you using `new` in your `main()` function?  `myList<int> a(5); myList<int> b(5);`  You created an issue when none needed to exist by using pointers instead of plain objects in your `main` function.  BTW, your program leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are many wholesome ways to solve your problem, still I will name **two**:-

- [Dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) your two pointers...

  ```
  (*a)+(*b);
  ```
- Just use normal *non-pointer* classes...

  ```
  myList<int> a = myList<int>(5);
  myList<int> b = myList<int>(5);
  // ...
  ```

Also, if you are using pointers, **don't** forget to free the pointer from memory using `delete` and assigning to `nullptr`... See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223399/deleting-a-pointer-in-c) for more information...